# Maximum value in column with filter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have in df 2 column - DATE_G, RES.

```
df['DATE_G'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_G'], format='%Y.%m.%d')
condition_11 = df['RES'] = 1
condition_12 = df['RES'] = 0
```

And I need
1) filter df on conditions 11 and 12.
2) find the maximum of the date column
3) subtract 1 day from the maximum

```
startdate = df['DATE_G'].max().where(condition_11 & condition_12) - 1
```

But I have:

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'where'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.max()` is returning the maximum value value, not a pd.Series which you can perform `.where()` on:

```
startdate = df.loc[df['DATE_G'] == df['DATE_G'].max()].where(condition_11 & condition_12)
final_startdate = startdate['DATE_G'] - pd.DateOffset(1)
```

Comment: TypeError: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [sub]

Comment: try the edited version. the where required all columns, not just the date series. note that final_startdate will still be a series